# SQL Server DB tasks, Detach, Backup and Restore

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am attaching My DB through vb.net code.

Now I request help for the following:

1. How to detach it using code (`uid=sa, pwd=abc123`)?
2. How to take backup?
3. How to restore backup?

Please note I want to do it all using vb.net code

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2
TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2008R2.Bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of AdventureWorks2008R2';
GO
```

Restore:

```
----Put database into single user mode (terminates open connections - else restore fails)
ALTER DATABASE YourDB
SET SINGLE_USER WITH
ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE


RESTORE DATABASE YourDB 
FROM DISK = 'D:\temp\YourDB.bak' 
WITH REPLACE 
,MOVE 'YourDB_Data' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\YourDB_Data.mdf'
,MOVE 'YourDB_Log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\YourDB_Data.ldf'


ALTER DATABASE YourDB SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

Detach:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'AdventureWorks',
@keepfulltextindexfile = N'true'
GO
```

Attach:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_attach_db @dbname = N'AdventureWorks2008R2', 
    @filename1 = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf', 
    @filename2 = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorks2008R2_log.ldf';
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I really have no idea how to use it.  Writing in vb does not work.

Comment: You use System.Data.SqlClient (.SqlCommand) to execute them. Everything with an (at) in front is a variable, and needs to be declared. Otherwise, just omit the variable name and equal sign.

Answer (score 2):

This article series is a great place to get started and see samples - also in VB.NET.

[Getting started with SMO in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=34)

And even if you encounter C# samples - there's always the online [Convert C# to VB.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) site to convert those to VB.NET